# How did run-parts get its name?

Tags: history

I understand what run-parts does but I would like to know why the program is called run-parts. I've never heard someone call an executable in a directory a part. Why did the author name it run-parts and what are the parts?

Comment: The [source code](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/debianutils/blob/master/run-parts.c#L11) says: "Based on run-parts.pl version 0.2, Copyright (C) 1994 Ian Jackson." I wonder if Ian Jackson remembers why after ~25 years. (Also, this would be around the time of [Debian 0.91](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/project-history/ch-releases.en.html).)

Comment: @muru I do find it a lot intuitive pointing to directories to run scripts (parts of a job?); as a latin based tongue speaker we also use a lot that expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ian Jackson wrote back:

> I probably named it.  I'm not sure why the etymology is not obvious.
>   It runs various parts.

And a follow-up on why it could have used the word "parts":

> They're just parts of the task to be run.

Answer (score 0):

As per `man 4 run-parts`

> Historically the crontab file contained configuration which called
>   run-parts on files in cron.{daily,weekly,monthly} directories.
>
> Crontabs is a historical name for the run-parts script and the
>   system crontab. The run-parts script runs all executables in the
>   specified directory. Run-parts runs all executables in the specified
>   directory. The execution of files can be allowed or denied by creating
>   file jobs.allow or jobs.deny which worked similar as other allow/deny
>   config files. The file must be created in the specified directory.

From [what is run-parts in /etc/crontab, and how do I use it](https://superuser.com/questions/402781/what-is-run-parts-in-etc-crontab-and-how-do-i-use-it)

> It will run every script that is found in a directory. For example,
>   if you do a listing of /etc/cron.hourly, you'll see that it's a
>   directory where you can put executable files to be run every hour.

So, what we can see is that run-parts is a script created for the convenience of running crontab jobs scatered in files in a directory, and the parts are each individual script.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question, it's just a restatement of my second sentence.

Comment: I have noticed now, running late here... maybe you are answering you own question I guess.